# Giving to believers vs non

Tags: matthew

Based on

Matthew 25:40
Truly I tell you, whatever you did for one of the least of these brothers and sisters of mine, you did for me

How do i give in the name of the Lord? Do i get rewards giving to non believers?

Comment: The problem is i lived in Muslim country, every homeless i saw on the streets is Muslim, i cant just ignore them? Or i dont have to give? Because you know store up heavenly treasures... i only say to them when i give that "i am Christian" but sometimes i forgot to tell.

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on christianity SE? I think it's more suited for that one.

Comment: I think it is a perfectly appropriate question on this site as it asks about the interpretation of a Bible verse.

Comment: Posting this as a Comment rather than an Answer because I can't be bothered to look up the verses of Scripture that backs this up: "How do i give in the name of the Lord?" With a joyful heart and a desire to help other people, rather than a sense of obligation or a desire for rewards. "Do i get rewards giving to non believers?" You get a bigger house in Heaven, after you die, but that isn't why you should be doing it. The fact you're asking about rewards indicates your thinking probably isn't where it should be.

Comment: @nick012000 'Not being bothered' is not a reason to post a comment rather than a proper answer. The site exists to provide an archive of data based on questions and answers. Comments are intended only to clarify matters pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Let us be very clear here.  The Bible is absolutely racially blind.

The main point of Jesus' parable of the Good Samaritan (Luke 10:25-37) drives this point home quite forcibly - the Samaritan was commended precisely because he regarded a person in need as his neighbour regardless of race!!  We need to take heed to Jesus' instruction to "go and do likewise" (V37).

There is no room in Christianity for racially selective love; and no room for denominationally or theologically selective love and compassion.  If a person is in need then as Christians we have a moral and ethical duty to attempt to serve that need.  Jesus again made this point in The Sheep and the Goats in Matt 25:31-46.

Again, Jesus makes this point even more strongly in Matt 5:43-48

> You have heard that it was said, ‘Love your neighbour and ‘Hate your
> enemy.’ 44But I tell you, love your enemies and pray for those who
> persecute you that you may be sons of your Father in heaven. He causes
> His sun to rise on **the evil and the good**, and sends rain on **the
> righteous and the unrighteous**. If you love those who love you, what
> reward will you get? Do not even tax collectors do the same? And if
> you greet only your brothers, what are you doing more than others? Do
> not even Gentiles do the same?  Be perfect, therefore, as your
> heavenly Father is perfect.

Ellicott Observes in commenting on Matt 25:40 -

> Inasmuch as ye have done it unto one of the least of these my
> brethren.--The words are true, in different degrees of intensity, in
> proportion as the relationship is consciously recognised, of every
> member of the family of man. Of all it is true that He, the Lord, who
> took their flesh and blood, "is not ashamed to call them brethren"
> (Hebrews 2:11). We have here, in its highest and divinest form, that
> utterance of sympathy which we admire even in one of like passions
> with ourselves. We find that He too "counts nothing human alien from
> Himself."

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even if all Christians are all equally a part of the Body of Christ, different people play different roles in that Body, and not all are equally gifted, and that's okay. Paul writes about this in his first letter to the Corinthians, chapter 12, verses 12 to 26.

Comment: For the modern reader, "Muslim" might be an adequate substitution for Samaritan, although some of the nuances of the comparison are lost.

Comment: Nothing about the question is remotely about race. It's clearly about different religions.

Comment: @curiousdannii - agreed.  I wanted to include that to ensure there was no doubt about the all-inclusiveness about Jesus' "brothers".

Answer (score 4):

It is a fundamental part of repentance that one should care about one's fellow human beings.

When John the Baptist came, preaching repentance, it was an essential part of his preaching :

> (10) And the people asked him, saying, What shall we do then? (11) He answereth and saith unto them, He that hath two coats, let him impart to him that hath none; and he that hath meat, let him do likewise.

> Luke 3: 10, 11

There is no question of a 'reward'. If someone is unclothed or hungry and I have extra clothing and extra food, I am to just give it to them.

And there is no consideration whatsoever about who the needy person is.

Just give it.

Answer (score 2):

Does God care only for those who are Christians? Impossible, for He is God of all (cf. Romans 3:29). That He cares for all people and nations, even for those who are in enmity with His chosen nation - Israel - is evident also from the Old Testament: see the book of Jonah. So, to whom He sent His only-begotten Son, to some people or to all mankind? Of course to all mankind (John 3:16), and that He cared and cares for non-believers before they accepted or even heard about Him is clearly stated by the inspired Paul (Romans 5:8).

This said, will not it be an evil and a stupidity in the eyes of God not to show mercy to non-Christians when He is merciful to them? And will not a charity and mercy to non-Christians be accounted to a person acting this charity as a virtue? In both questions the answer is a big "Yes". Then, if nothing should hinder a good Christian to be merciful towards non-Christians, what can hinder the same good Christian to be merciful to his fellow-Christians, who are mystically a part of his own body (1 Cor. 12:27)?